# Using a Date Picker with a UITextField and disabling other input

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uidatepicker

So i've got a dat picker setup as a UITextField's `inputView`, all is working well. The problem however is that when you select the text field (and the picker shows up), you're still able to type in letters (on a simulator using computer's keyboard). How can I set it up so that when you tap on the text field and the date picker shows up, you cannot enter any additional text?

Answer (score -1):

You can code your `UIViewController` to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, assign the delegate for textField and then write the following function in your view controller :-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: Doing that means that even the datePicker doesn't show up. I need the date picker to show up, I just don't want anything other than the date to be able to be input.